# why i am getting an error when i try to over ride a method

Tags: java, methods, overriding

Hello and good morning guys I'm new to Java, I've encountered some problems while doing my home work. It is related to inheritance.

I need to create a super class named Employee where the variable name and Employee number are kept. And then I need to create a displayInfo() methods to print all the variables.

Then I've been assigned to create a subclass where i calculate the salary and make an overridden method to print the variables from the super class and add the salary to it using the displayInfo() method. But when I try to use it in the subclass, there is an error shown up where it says:

the field employee.number is not visible

Is there any way I can solve this?

Thank you very much for your help! Here is the code I've tried so far

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String date;
    
    public Employee()
    {
        
    }
    
    public Employee(String name,String number,String date)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.number=number;
        this.date=date;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    
    public void displayInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("Name = "+ name + "Number = "+number+ " Date = " + date);
                    
    }

}
\\ my sub class
public class ProductionWorker extends Employee {

    private int shift;// 1 = day, 2 = night 
    private double HoursOfWorking;// day = RM10, night = RM12.50
    
    public ProductionWorker(int shift,int HoursOfWorking)
    {
        this.shift=shift;
        this.HoursOfWorking=HoursOfWorking;
    }
    
    public int getShift()
    {
        return shift;
    }
    public double getHoursOfWorking()
    {
        return HoursOfWorking;
    }
    
    public double calculateSalary()
    {
        if(shift==1)
        {
            return HoursOfWorking * 10 * 20;
        }
        else
        {
            return HoursOfWorking * 12.5 * 20;
        }
        
    }
    

    public void displayInfo() // this is where the error is encountered
    {
        System.out.println("Name = "+ name + "Number = "+number+ " Date = " + date + "Sallary = "+ calculateSalary());
                    
    }


}
```

Comment: So, the error you getting is because you're overriding `displayInfo`, it's because you're trying to access properties/fields which are `private` and which are not accessible to sub/child classes - this is where you should provide "getters" for these properties (and setters where appropriate)

Comment: The fileds in super class is private so you't read them，you can make field protected or call super class method

Answer (score 1):

As the below fields are private

```
private String name;
private String number;
private String date;
```

you do not have access to them in the subclass, so either make them `protected` or use the `getter` methods.

Answer (score 0):

since number is declared as private it is not visible you have to use
your `getNumber()` method

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I actually take back my answer below. That will only work if the classes are in the same file like this:

```java
class OuterClass
{
     public class Employee
     {
          // ...
     }

     public class ProductionWorker extends Employee
     {
          // ...
     }
}
```

You can either change the variables visibility to public/protected or use the getter methods you defined in your `Employee` class. I'd recommend using the getter methods.

---

In order to access the values of the `Employee` class in your subclass `ProductionWorker`, you have to use the `super` keyword.

```java
public void displayInfo()
{
     System.out.println("Name = " + super.name + "Number = " + super.number + " Date = " + super.date + "Salary = " + calculateSalary());
}
```

Comment: but when ever i use the super key words, when i print it will appear "null" i dont know why

Comment: That's because you are not setting the values of ```name```, ```number```, and ```date```. You defined those variables but you never actually set a value to them in your ```ProductionWorker``` class.